# Non responsive MediaWiki skin

Tags: responsive-design, mediawiki

I installed the latest version of MediaWiki (1.23.1) and was surprised not having a responsive design as Wikipedia has. Is there a way to enable such feature (if it exists) or should I switch to another wiki engine?

Comment: MediaWiki completely un-responsive, and so is Wikipedia. Wikimedia wikis use [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend](Extension:MobileFrontend) to serve a mobile friendly webpage, so no responsiveness there. Having once created [a responsive skin](http://xn--ssongsmat-v2a.nu) myself I can assure you that it is a lot of work, especially when it comes to special pages and such.

Comment: It's hard to realize... It is completely unacceptable for such a big project as MediaWiki in my opinion. We're in 2014. Thanks for your answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same responsiveness as Wikipedia have, you need to install [Extension:Mobile Frontend](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMobileFrontend).